# just_audio custom source not requesting enough

Tags: just-audio

I have a service that streams bytes of music. This service using gRPC protocol so I can't use `player.setUrl`. Instead I add bytes into a `List<int>` named musicBytes. And I created a StreamAudioSource named as MyCustomSource.

```
class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
  var musicService = GetIt.I.get<MusicService>();
  print("initial request: $start, $end");
  start ??= 0;
  end ??= musicService.musicBytes.length;
  print("request: $start, $end");
  return StreamAudioResponse(
    sourceLength: 5319140, // All bytes after stream
    contentLength: end - start,
    offset: start,
    stream: Stream.value(musicService.musicBytes.sublist(start, end)),
    contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
  );
 }
}
```

But this request function called just two times after setting it. And audio plays just for a short time.

Should I implement different AudioSource or I should use something else.

platform: win10

Comment: Well the length of the play is the bitlength .. but maybe the length of the bytes is less number than the time to play those bytes.  So maybe you need another trigger event that calculates the play length by time and not byte count?  Maybe even calculate the value into a table to use to preuse to feed into your function to help it know to play the full song time.

Comment: @easleyfixed I didn't understand properly. Are you suggesting changing sourceLength. If so, it doesn't work

Comment: I suspect that the length it is testing for, is the length of the file in bytes and not the length of the time required to play the file if that makes sense.